# Misaligned pointer use with std::shared_ptr<NSDate> dereference

Tags: nsdate, shared-ptr, objective-c++, ubsan, manual-retain-release

I am working in a legacy codebase with a large amount of Objective-C++ written using manual retain/release. Memory is managed using lots of C++ `std::shared_ptr<NSMyCoolObjectiveCPointer>`, with a suitable deleter passed in on construction that calls `release` on the contained object. This seems to work great; however, when enabling UBSan, it complains about misaligned pointers, usually when dereferencing the shared_ptrs to do some work.

I've searched for clues and/or solutions, but it's difficult to find technical discussion of the ins and outs of Objective-C object pointers, and even more difficult to find *any* discussion about Objective-C++, so here I am.

Here is a full Objective-C++ program that demonstrates my problem. When I run this on my Macbook with UBSan, I get a misaligned pointer issue in `shared_ptr::operator*`:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <memory>

class DateImpl {
public:
    DateImpl(NSDate* date) : _date{[date retain], [](NSDate* date) { [date release]; }} {}

    NSString* description() const { return [&*_date description]; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<NSDate> _date;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        DateImpl date{[NSDate distantPast]};
        NSLog(@"%@", date.description());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get this in the call to `DateImpl::description`:

```
runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xe2b7fda734fc266f for type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<NSDate>::element_type' (aka 'NSDate'), which requires 8 byte alignment
0xe2b7fda734fc266f: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
```

I *suspect* that there is something awry with the usage of `&*` to "cast" the `shared_ptr<NSDate>` to an `NSDate*`. I think I could probably work around this issue by using `.get()` on the shared_ptr instead, but I am genuinely curious about what is going on. Thanks for any feedback or hints!

Comment: Can you log the address passed to the `shared_ptr` constructor, i.e. the result of `[date retain]`? How does that match up to the pointer reported by UBSan?

Comment: It's the same. I've sifted through some of the red herrings in the question and got to the core--check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some red herrings here: `shared_ptr`, manual retain/release, etc. But I ended up discovering that even this very simple code (with ARC enabled) causes the ubsan hit:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate& d = *[NSDate distantPast];
        NSLog(@"%@", &d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to simply be an issue with `[NSDate distantPast]` (and, incidentally, `[NSDate distantFuture]`, but not, for instance, `[NSDate date]`). I conclude that these must be singleton objects allocated sketchily/misaligned-ly somewhere in the depths of Foundation, and when you dereference them it causes a misaligned pointer read.

(Note it does *not* happen when the code is simply `NSLog(@"%@", &*[NSDate distantPast])`. I assume this is because the compiler simply collapses `&*` on a raw pointer into a no-op. It doesn't for the `shared_ptr` case in the original question because `shared_ptr` overloads `operator*`. Given this, I believe there is no easy way to make this happen in pure Objective-C, since you can't separate the `&` operation from the `*` operation, like you can when C++ references are involved [by storing the temporary result of `*` in an `NSDate&`].)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to ever use a "bare" `NSDate` type. Objective-C objects should always be used with a pointer-to-object type (e.g. `NSDate *`), and you are never supposed to get the "type behind the pointer".

In particular, on 64-bit platforms, Objective-C object pointers can sometimes not be valid pointers, but rather be "tagged pointers" which store the "value" of the object in certain bits of the pointer, rather than as an actual allocated object. You must always let the Objective-C runtime machinery deal with Objective-C object pointers. Dereferencing it as a regular C/C++ pointer can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Really interesting info about the tagged pointers. FWIW I do in fact remember seeing `__NSTaggedDate*` show up in the debugger with regard to `[NSDate distantPast]`. Makes total sense that dereferencing such a thing would explode.